# Firefox, PHP Headers and application/octet-stream

Tags: firefox

We have a page that outputs a file using PHP headers, so when you visit the page the download prompts up.

Randomly, the page will return a file `application/octet-stream`, other times it will return the correct thing.

It works prefectly in Chrome, IE, etc.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wNev7.png]

This only happens in Firefox and it is completely random.

Basically, it outputs as a `application/octet-stream` instead of the correct one.

After some more digging, I found the following:

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/800957

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/746116

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/699834

Comment: It's quite hard to judge without the code.

Comment: Can't say anything without some code or something, but maybe the cache is the problem? Try adding `Cache-control: no-cache` header to the response.

Comment: I've edited the question with an example code of our page.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? My bet is at the times nothing comes thrrough, the script crashes with an error.

Comment: I've also updated the question with an image of what randomly gets outputted.

Comment: @Pekka, if it was something to do with PHP why would it work 100% correctly in other browsers and only cause this in Firefox?

Comment: @Latox ah, I overread that. Weird. Can you post the literal response headers from Firebug?

Comment: I've just done some reading on Google about why Firefox outputs as application/octet-stream - please read the bottom of my question :)

Comment: @Latox I think the headers get screwed up somehow. If you can reproduce the problem, it would be great if you could post them

Comment: I've updated the question with some links, it seems to be a common Firefox problem and I'm just looking for a solution >.<

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3854/discussion-between-latox-and-pekka)

Comment: If it's entirely Firefox's fault, breaking downloads for no reason, I suppose there's nothing you can do on server side to fix it. If it has to do with the headers that get send, you need to show the headers that get sent